# javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be created

Tags: java, xml, multithreading, sax

In my code I use multiple threads to parse multiple xml responses at the same time. My code is basically like this

```
private static final JAXBContext JAXB_CONTEXT = JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXB_CONTEXT_PATH);

executorService = newFixedThreadPool(5);

builder.executeAsync(executorService).whenComplete((result, ex) -> {
    _parseResponse(result);
});

private void _parseResponse(@Nonnull final byte[] response) {
    final ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(response);
    Object responseObj = JAXB_CONTEXT.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(stream);
}
```

But I got a lot of such errors when executing the above code. Anyone has idea of what could be the cause? Or how to get more detailed info about the failure? Thanks!!

```
Exception when parsing a response  <Executors.newThreadPoolExecutor-8-0>
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be created
    at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:305)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:261)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:147)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.getXMLReader(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:113)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:170)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:209)
    at _parseResponse
    at MarketingApiCaller.lambda$execute$0
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at com.tripadvisor.core.rpc.ServiceCallBuilderImpl.lambda$executeAsyncRaw$5(ServiceCallBuilderImpl.java:989)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:930)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:907)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478)
    at com.TripResearch.util.concurrent.SelfAwareRunnable._run(SelfAwareRunnable.java:43)
    at com.TripResearch.object.RequestContext.with(RequestContext.java:315)
    at com.TripResearch.util.concurrent.SelfAwareRunnable.run(SelfAwareRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be created
    at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:302)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1211)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1220)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:1267)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:1266)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1269)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1299)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1384)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder$1.run(FactoryFinder.java:287)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:283)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: 1) What JRE are you using? 2) Show your Maven or Gradle config.

Comment: Most probably  due to conflicted jar in the build path, Also if you are using JRE5 then it must be the issue try to switch to upper version of JRE

Comment: The prefixing of Java class names with package names like java.base and java.xml suggests to me it might be quite a recent Java release, or some custom class loading environment? I don't know if that creates any special requirements.

Comment: I get a shell into the k8s pod and "java -version" shows that it is running openjdk version "11.0.3"

Comment: @JiechaoWang, had you got any fix for this? facing the same issue.

Comment: @Vicky unfortunately no